# Change the visibility of a button when location==null

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In method onCreate i have button:

```
    connection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            {
                   GoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
```

and at the very bottom android studio generated:

```
@Override

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) 
    {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;

    }

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) 
    {

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);

    }
```

And now i describe my problem:
Trying to hide my connection button when location == null, and 'else' unhide.

i found on stack this method:

```
button.setEnabled(false/true);
```

but i don't now where i should place this method

What to do to make it work?

Comment: *"but i don't now where i should place this method"* what about inside `if (location == null)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding is done using `View.setVisibility(int)` - options are `View.GONE` (completely hides the View, other Views fill its space); `View.INVISIBLE` (hides the View but it still occupies the layout space); `View.VISIBLE` (shows the View, again occupying the space).

So as people commented before:

```
if (location == null) {
    myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To invisible or visible button use:

```
if (location == null) {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // remove the element but used the space.
            or
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE); // remove element with used space taken by that element
}else{
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```